# java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Illegal footer: -property-named-idpCertificate

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, runtime-error

nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Illegal footer: -property-named-idpCertificate

I try to resolve the error but I don't know, why it happy in My project and what am I doing for this Issue?

Comment: Hi fatemehparsafar, can you include the relevant code that caused this error in your question please?